# Color css property not affecting color of font awesome icons

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome

I'm unable to change the color of the font awesome icons in our project (using the color property in css). I think the way we're loading our font awesome icons might be affecting our ability to change their color.

Before someone marks this as a duplicate, please take a look at the jsfiddle below.

You will see, from the html (at lines 7 and 10) that we're loading in a pre-defined set of fa icons from our own server. This is because, due to the nature of my organisation's work, we're not permitted to load external files.

https://jsfiddle.net/moosefetcher/dnjjy015/1/

Here is the html:

```
<div class="page">
  <div id="fb-user-research">
    <span class="fb-checkbox">
      <input id="fb-user-research-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="fb-checkbox"/>
      <label for="fb-user-research-checkbox" id="fb-visible-checkbox">
        <svg class="unchecked fa-square-0">
          <use xlink:href="~/Areas/CL/Content/app/images/icons/icon-svg-defs.svg#fa-square-o" />
        </svg>
        <svg class="checked fa-check-square">
          <use xlink:href="~/Areas/CL/Content/app/images/icons/icon-svg-defs.svg#fa-check-square" />
        </svg>
      </label>
    </span>
    <div id="fb-user-research-texts">
      <p>Placeholder text here</p>
      <p>Disclaimer here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
.page {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#fb-user-research {
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
        margin: 44px 0px 14px 0px;
        padding: 15px 15px;
    }

    #fb-user-research input {
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: #333333;
    }

    #fb-user-research input {
        float: left;
    }

    #fb-user-research #fb-user-research-texts {
        width: 90%;
        float: left;
    }

    #fb-user-research div p {
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }

    #fb-user-research div p:first-child {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #fb-user-research div p:last-child {
        color: #888888;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }
    .fb-checkbox {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        #fb-user-research #fb-user-research-texts {
            width: 85%;
            float: left;
        }
        .fb-checkbox > [type="checkbox"] {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .fb-checkbox {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .fb-checkbox > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~  #fb-visible-checkbox .checked {
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 1;
        color: #0099dd;
    }

    .fb-checkbox > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~  #fb-visible-checkbox .unchecked {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #fb-visible-checkbox > svg {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;        
    }

    #fb-visible-checkbox .unchecked {
        background-color: grey;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #fb-visible-checkbox .checked {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        color: #0099dd;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
```

To be clear, when working in my dev environment, the icons load fine. The question I'm asking is:

**Is loading the font awesome icons like we do (as shown in the jsfiddle) affecting our ability to change their color?**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using the font version of the FontAwesome icons.  You are using the SVG versions.

SVG doesn't use `color` to change the fill color of shapes.  It uses `fill`.

You will need to at least change the CSS to using `fill` instead of `color`.  You might also need to make other changes, but I can't tell you for sure because you haven't included your external SVG file.

Also, be aware that external `<use>` references, like you are using, don't work in IE (last I checked).  You may need to inline your SVG in your HTML if you care about that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if loading the font awesome icon  affecting our ability to change their color, but you can change your text color by overriding its css property by adding this css:

```
 #fb-user-research #fb-user-research-texts p{
        color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `background-color` of icons. 
Since you use svg icons, it wont support `color`

If you are using `<i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>` for implementing font awesome, you change the color by `color: red`